# Update a table on select change

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a form in which there is a drop down list and several text fields.
In the same page, I created a table below the form to display inserted data with the form.
This table is empty in the beginning, now, what I want to do is to display only records related to selected item from the drop down list.
To clarify things, let me give you a simple example:

- Drop down list=>List of clients
- Table=>client details

Once I select a client, his details must appear in the table.
So, How to make this?

Comment: writing full code will be impossible, its more like a client requirement

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."

Comment: I'm not asking for code @Arun Killu, I need to know what technology to use and steps to make this happen

Comment: Looks like you want to use AJAX calls

Comment: Before doing this stuff learn the basics. To the looks of your question you are not looking for a php mysql solution. You need JS/Jquery to detect a changing select and then load data based on the id given form the option element which has been selected.

Comment: @Anibel ya i am sorry for that remark

Comment: @ArunKillu, no worry my friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do as,

```
<select name="demo" id="demo" onchange="callAjax();">
```

**JS/Jquery**

```
function callAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: destinationUrl, // call your php file
        data: content, // pass the parameters needed in php, select option values
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) { // echo the table html from your php file
            $('#SuccessDiv').html(data); //data is populated in `successDiv`
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Question is not tagged with jQuery, and no jQuery is present in the OP's question so your answer should use vanilla javascript.

Comment: @Ajith S It works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<select onchange="return getval(this);">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<div id="clientdetails"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getval(sel) {
   var client = sel.value;
    var htm = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "client.php",
    data: "client=" + client,
    async: false
    }).responseText;

    if(htm)
    {
        $("#clientdetails").html(htm);
        return true;
        // Uncomment the following line in your application
        //return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#clientdetails").html("no result found");

        return false;
    }
}
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
// database connection
$client_id = $_REQUEST['client'];
$sql = mysql_query("select * from your_table where your_id =".$client_id);
$res=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo "Client_id :" .$res['id'];
......
?>
```